# Enumeration with multiple aligned question:answer blocks

Tags: enumerate

I think the title is not very informative, but I think the following example demonstrates what I'd like to achieve very well.

```
(a) Question:   Text text text text text text text text text text
                text text text text text text text text text text
                text text text text text text text text text text

    Answer:     Text text text text text text text text text text
                text text text text text text text text text text
                text text text text text text text text text text

(b) Question:   Text text text text text text text text text text
                text text text text text text text text text text
                text text text text text text text text text text

    Answer:     Text text text text text text text text text text
                text text text text text text text text text text
                text text text text text text text text text text
```

How would you solve this?

Comment: Why not using a table?

Comment: Because I think there are much more elegant ways of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

One way:

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,parskip} % dummy text 
\newcounter{que}
\newcommand\question{
\par\bigskip\stepcounter{que}%
\noindent\hangindent7em%
\makebox[2em][l]{(\alph{que})}%
\makebox[5em][s]{Question:\quad}}
\newcommand\answer{\par\medskip\noindent\hangindent7em%
\makebox[2em][l]{}%
\makebox[5em][r]{Answer:\quad}}
\newenvironment{questions}{\setcounter{que}{0}}{\par\bigskip}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-2]
\begin{questions}
\question \lipsum[2][1-2]
\answer \lipsum[3][1-2]
\question \lipsum[4][1-4]
\answer \lipsum[5][1-4]
\end{questions}

\lipsum[9][1-2]\par
\lipsum[10][1-3]

\begin{questions}
\question \lipsum[6][1-2]
\answer \lipsum[7][1-6]
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```